# Assign String variable in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a execute sql task in SSIS that I try to store a string value

this is the query

```
Declare @IdList nvarchar(max)
select @IdList = coalesce( @IdList + ''',''', '') + ID from table
Select @IdList = '''' + @IdList 
Select @IdList
```

The result looks like

```
'abc','bcd','def','fds'
```

and I try to store this value into String variable in SSIS

```
result set: single row
result name: 0 
Variable Name: String_Contact
```

this is the error I got

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: The value type (__ComObject) can only be converted to variables of type Object.
[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "String_Contact": "The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::String_Contact" differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
```

".

Anyone know what's the issue?

thanks

Comment: Can you try adding a Set @IdList='' after the declaration and see if that works? Also your type is nvarchar(max) which SSIS would intrepret as DT_NTEXT. You can try with an nvarchar(1000).

Comment: Will try that, thanks! but for the data type, the length of the string might exceed 100000 so I have to use nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 8):

Try to change the data type of the variable from String to Object.

If you assign varchar(max) to a string [SSIS] variable. there might be chance of overflow error since strings in SSIS are limited to 8000 chars in length.

But you can assign nvarchar(max) to Object.

You can process object by using For Each Loop Container setting Enumerator as "For Each ADO Enumerator" or by Script Task as

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleDa.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::variable"].Value);
```

use dt as regular DataTable.

Resources:

[How To Read Object Type Variable In Script Task](http://sqlage.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/ssis-how-to-read-object-type-variable.html)

[Using the SSIS Object Variable as a Result Set Enumerator](http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/05/28/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-result-set-enumerator/)

[Execute SQL Task into an object variable - Shred it with a Foreach loop](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/07/04/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Execute-SQL-Task-into-an-object-variable-_2D00_-Shred-it-with-a-Foreach-loop.aspx)

[Mapping Full Resultset with Execute SQL Task to Object Variable](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5230.ssis-mapping-full-resultset-with-execute-sql-task-to-object-variable.aspx)

To use variable in SQLStatement property follow [this](http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/) thread.

Comment: it will work, but how can I reference this object variable in my data flow source in this case? ..
My goal is to use the variable in the source query such as: 

Select * from table where ID in (@variable)

Comment: Why don't you use  a lookup task if you are just just looking up ids?

Comment: that's what I am using now, but I am trying different thing to see if performance increased. cause I am dealing with million of rows here. thanks for the comment again

Answer (score 1):

Vikamsinh's answer is technically correct, but he gives you the wrong solution.

To put it simply: you cannot do what you wish to do if the string variable you wish to insert into your SQL command exceeds 8000 characters. Since you'll have to use an NVARCHAR(MAX), SSIS will only interpret that as an Object variable, and you can't convert it to a String.

According to your comments, you might have a string of 100,000 characters. (So many IDs!) S

There is a pretty simple solution, though: use a Script Source Component instead of a standard source component. Then you can cast your object variable's value to a .NET String Type, build up your SQL statement there, and execute it against your connection to read in your results.

Here's [the MSDN sample on using a Script Source Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx).

---

That all being said, is your original source a large set of data? Could you change this to a "select fields from table" source and use a Lookup to filter using the IDs you're drawing out of your Execute SQL task? Or (even better) can you push your IDs into a staging table on your source database and then use a join to limit your source query to the rows you want to intake?

Comment: Thanks, now I know the reason why it's failing and the option to fix it.